# Create custom note boxes

Tags: macros, environments

I am trying to create custom info boxes (very similar as in `awesomebox` package).

The and everything sims is fine except when the box is not surrounded with some text. Then I get an error `There's no line here to end`.

I guess the error is because of `\bigskip\newline` in my macros. I used it to create extra paddings on top and bottom of the environment and macros

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\parindent=0ex
\usepackage{xcolor}

% RED
\definecolor{redSeven}{rgb}{0.94, 0.24, 0.24}
\definecolor{redNine}{rgb}{0.79, 0.16, 0.16}

% ORANGE
\definecolor{orangeSeven}{rgb}{0.97, 0.4, 0.03}
\definecolor{orangeNine}{rgb}{0.85, 0.28, 0.06}

%    BANS ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\banBox}[2][ban]{%
    \bigskip\newline
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering
        \textcolor{redSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}
    \end{minipage}%
    \textcolor{redSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \textcolor{redNine}{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \smallskip\newline
}

\newenvironment{banEnv}[1][ban]%
{\bigskip\newline%
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering%
        \textcolor{redSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \textcolor{redSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}%
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \color{redNine}}
    {\end{minipage}\bigskip\newline}

%    WARNINGS ------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\warningBox}[2][exclamation-triangle]{%
    \bigskip \newline
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering
        \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}
    \end{minipage}%
    \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \textcolor{orangeNine}{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \newline
}

\newenvironment{warningEnv}[1][exclamation-triangle]%
{\bigskip\newline
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering%
        \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}%
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \color{orangeNine}}
    {\end{minipage}\bigskip\newline}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

Comment this line or Delete any commented line bellow
\banBox{Ban box.}
% A
\begin{banEnv}
    Ban environment.\\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
    Earum odit quia maiores nisi illum reiciendis aspernatur.
\end{banEnv}
% B
\warningBox{Warning box.}
% C
\begin{warningEnv}
    Warning environment.\\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
    Earum odit quia maiores nisi illum reiciendis aspernatur.
\end{warningEnv}
% D

\end{document}
```

**Updated:**
The worst case if is no line in between.

```
\begin{document}

    \banBox{Ban box.}

    \begin{banEnv}
        Ban environment.\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
        Earum odit quia maiores nisi illum reiciendis aspernatur.
    \end{banEnv}

    \warningBox{Warning box.}

    \begin{warningEnv}
        Warning environment.\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
        Earum odit quia maiores nisi illum reiciendis aspernatur.
    \end{warningEnv}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added a space character before `\bigskip\newline` for `\newline` command. Such as:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\parindent=0ex
\usepackage{xcolor}

% RED
\definecolor{redSeven}{rgb}{0.94, 0.24, 0.24}
\definecolor{redNine}{rgb}{0.79, 0.16, 0.16}

% ORANGE
\definecolor{orangeSeven}{rgb}{0.97, 0.4, 0.03}
\definecolor{orangeNine}{rgb}{0.85, 0.28, 0.06}

%    BANS ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\banBox}[2][ban]{%
    \ \bigskip\newline         % <----------------- added \ and space
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering
        \textcolor{redSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}
    \end{minipage}%
    \textcolor{redSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \textcolor{redNine}{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \smallskip\newline
}

\newenvironment{banEnv}[1][ban]%
{\bigskip\newline%
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering%
        \textcolor{redSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \textcolor{redSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}%
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \color{redNine}}
    {\end{minipage}\bigskip\newline}

%    WARNINGS ------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\warningBox}[2][exclamation-triangle]{%
    \bigskip \newline
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering
        \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}
    \end{minipage}%
    \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \textcolor{orangeNine}{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \newline
}

\newenvironment{warningEnv}[1][exclamation-triangle]%
{\bigskip\newline
    \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering%
        \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}%
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \color{orangeNine}}
    {\end{minipage}\bigskip\newline}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%Comment this line or Delete any commented line bellow
\banBox{Ban box.}
 A
\begin{banEnv}
    Ban environment.\\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
    Earum odit quia maiores nisi illum reiciendis aspernatur.
\end{banEnv}
 B
\warningBox{Warning box.}
 C
\begin{warningEnv}
    Warning environment.\\
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
    Earum odit quia maiores nisi illum reiciendis aspernatur.
\end{warningEnv}
 D
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM:**

If we remove the A, B, C and D lines, output is follow:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \parindent=0ex
    \usepackage{xcolor}

    % RED
    \definecolor{redSeven}{rgb}{0.94, 0.24, 0.24}
    \definecolor{redNine}{rgb}{0.79, 0.16, 0.16}

    % ORANGE
    \definecolor{orangeSeven}{rgb}{0.97, 0.4, 0.03}
    \definecolor{orangeNine}{rgb}{0.85, 0.28, 0.06}

    %    BANS ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    \newcommand{\banBox}[2][ban]{%
        \ \bigskip\newline
        \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering
            \textcolor{redSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}
        \end{minipage}%
        \textcolor{redSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}
        \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
            \textcolor{redNine}{#2}
        \end{minipage}
        \smallskip\newline
    }

    \newenvironment{banEnv}[1][ban]%
    {\ \bigskip\newline%
        \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering%
            \textcolor{redSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \textcolor{redSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}%
        \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
            \color{redNine}}
        {\end{minipage}\bigskip\newline}

    %    WARNINGS ------------------------------------------------------------------

    \newcommand{\warningBox}[2][exclamation-triangle]{%
       \ \bigskip \newline
        \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering
            \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}
        \end{minipage}%
        \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}
        \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
            \textcolor{orangeNine}{#2}
        \end{minipage}
        \newline
    }

    \newenvironment{warningEnv}[1][exclamation-triangle]%
    {\ \bigskip\newline
        \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}\centering%
            \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\fontsize{16}{24}\faicon{#1}}%
        \end{minipage}%
        \textcolor{orangeSeven}{\vrule width 3pt \hspace{14pt}}%
        \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
            \color{orangeNine}}
        {\end{minipage}\bigskip\newline}

    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   \begin{document}

    \banBox{Ban box.}

    \begin{banEnv}
        Ban environment.\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\\
        Earum odit quia maiores nisi illum reiciendis aspernatur.
    \end{banEnv}

    \warningBox{Warning box.}

    \begin{warningEnv}
        Warning environment.\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
        Earum odit quia maiores nisi illum reiciendis aspernatur.
    \end{warningEnv}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it does'n work if you remove the text in between (A, B, C, D)

Comment: It works. Check out my addendum.

Comment: @ferahfeza I like it. My congratulations.

Comment: @Igor, add `\ ` to each `\bigskip\newline`

Comment: @Igor, your welcome.

Comment: @ferahfeza may I ask you to direct me where i can find some info/documentation to learn why the space was necessary? Because i don't get why it worked

Comment: This is a good documentaiton for Line and Page Breaking http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm#newline